Is it ok to use meta not to ask questions?
I saw a bunch of "questions" here on meta where the author actually wanted to make a proclamation (in Italian un proclama) in the form of an absolute statement about what is the correct way of using the site how they think other users should use the site.
Examples:

Common misconceptions when discussing language
This is not a site for Italians! (I actually agree with this and I have upvoted it, but still it's not a question)
Incorrect way of classifying North and South in terms of language

AFAIK meta is for asking questions discussing the policies, not to impose one's views without any possibility for other people to answer (since a proclamation is not a question).
The title says it all: is it ok?
I personally flagged a couple of them with "Unclear what you are asking" but I would like to know what the consensus is about this.

Please can you link these questions you refer to here? Would help discussing the matter.

I didn't because I was afraid of facing backlashes and negative consequences on my profile but... well, since you asked. Here you go.

There are no backlashes, I believe we should be all committed to creating a good product, so every criticism is well accepted. I have seen the questions but I don't agree with them being inappropriate here, so long as they're tagged for discussion and the poster is ready to accept different opinions.

«I have seen the questions» Well, that's my point: these are not questions. I hope we can all agree on this. There is not even a question mark, only statements.

As for my (not?-)question («Common misconceptions...») the intent to gather responses and opinions, and possibly to arrive at a consensus, was in the words “I believe it would be useful to clarify some points” etc. I meant this as “let's discuss in order to clarify them” but I see that it can be construed as “listen to what I have to say”. If this is the case, I'll be glad to rephrase my question.

By the way, @martina, yours should be an answer. ;)

@AndreaLazzarotto somehow yes, but it just reinforces Charo's one down here, which I agree with.

Meta is for discussion. To me its pretty clear what those posts were about and I dont feel that a "what you think about that?" at the end would have made them be any different.

How do you discuss with someone who says "this is it" (imagine mic drop scene here)? How do you answer a non question?

In my opinion, such posts are OK if they can fit under the tag discussion whose usage guidance stays

The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.

That is, it could be that there is not an explicit question written in the body of the post, but the aim of the OP is someway to say: "This is what I think about this point concerning the correct use of the site. What is your opinion about that?" Anyway, it could be a good practice trying to be more explicit so as to really write this kind of questions in the post. By the way, some of these kind of posts are written by Community Managers of SE. See, for instance, this one: Help ensure English speakers can participate on meta.
Edit: 
I have find this post concerning a similar discussion in another Meta Stack Exchange site: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/a-friendly-reminder-that-this-is-meta-questions-here-do-not-have-to-be-question?cb=1.

Sorry but I don't understand. The description you quoted explicity mentions the question you are asking, not the statements you are forcing on other people. The example you posted looks just a reminder of an already established "common sense / good education" rule, not the kind of explicit dictator attitude I've seen from a bunch of other users: "I am right, we do this way, shut up".

@AndreaLazzarotto: I haven't seen such a "explicit dictator attitude" in any of the posts written recently as a question here on Meta. But, as I have tried to say in my answer, maybe we should establish the good practice of writting explicitly in our posts that we are asking for the opinion of the Community with the goal of reaching a consensus.

Rather than "a good practice" IMHO it is a necessity.
